# updated json file not showing in public link

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I got some problem when updating my json file which located in a bucket, and will be called by a html page. I will update my json file every 5 minutes from the command line, and this can be done. However, even though the json file itself is updated and set to be public, the public link is still showing the old content not the new content.

If I click the json file, I can see that the content has been changed, but if I click the public link, the content still remains not updated.

Does anybody know how much time it takes for Google Cloud Storage to load the buffer so that the new content will be shown in the public link?

Or is there any method to update the json file and get the public link updating instantly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, publicly visible objects accessed anonymously have a cache-control header set to 1 hour. You can override this when you upload a new object by explicitly setting the cacheControl metadata to something else.

If you're using gsutil to upload the object, you could do it like this:

```
gsutil -h "Cache-Control:no-cache, max-age=0" \
    cp -a public-read myfile.json gs://mybucket
```

Comment: Thank you., Brandon. I think your answer totally make sense, that is how much time it takes to get the updated public link, and I do use gsutil to update the json file. However, I tried your method, setting the Cache-Control, but still no luck. even I delete the file, and upload a new file with same name, still not working.  Let me play around and see whether I can get some solution from your answer.

Comment: made it working, thank you so so much~~~~ spent a few hours on this, totally stuck in it. thank you!!

Comment: Yep, I'll bet you it took exactly one hour for it to start working for you :)