# JSON file with same name in GCP bucket not updating quickly when try to over write

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a file in GCP bucket when I try to update the file with new changes it's not reflecting quickly in public url. If I click the json file, I can see that the content has been changed, but if I click the public url, the content still remains not updated. I have used node.js. My code will look like this

```
const destFileName = 'data.json';
const file = myBucket.file(destFileName);
const fData = files;
passthroughStream.write(fData);
passthroughStream.end();
async function streamFileUpload() {
  passthroughStream.pipe(file.createWriteStream({ metadata: {
    cacheControl: 'no-store'
  }})).on('finish', () => {
    console.log('Stream file upload function is completed ');
  });
  console.log(`${destFileName} uploaded to ${bucketName}`);
}
await streamFileUpload();
```

Is there any method to update the json file and get the public link updating instantly?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you gone through this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152224/updated-json-file-not-showing-in-public-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publicly readable objects default to being cacheable. If you want a public link to offer strong consistency, you'll need to explicitly disable caching for that object, for example by setting a cacheControl property like `no-cache, max-age=0`. If you're uploading with `gsutil`, you could do it like this:

```
gsutil -h "Cache-Control:no-cache, max-age=0" \
    cp -a public-read myfile.json gs://mybucket
```

Alternately, you could put some random URL query parameter into your URL to skip any caches between you and Cloud Storage, like `dodgeCache=12345`.

Comment: thank you @Brandon Yarbrough for your answer. I need to do this from codes so I will take this properties and will try to implement using node.js.